# Error running OPTIMAL algorithm

Tags: c

****C:>pager_OPTIMAL test 100
    File used fifo-test, resident set size 200

**Error restoring the reference stream position
  Error was:: Invalid argument****/**

```
pt_entry pte[MAX_PAGE];         /* page table */
int mem_size;               /* physical memory size in page frames */
list free_list_head;            /* free list */ 
list res_set_head;          /* resident set */
int total_fault = 0;            /* total number of page faults */
int total_ref = 0;          /* total number of memory references */
FILE *stream;               


 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   /*   FILE *stream;*/

if (argc != 3)
{
    printf("The format is: pager file_name memory_size.\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("File used %s, resident set size %d\n", argv[1], atoi(argv[2]));

if ((stream = fopen(argv[1], "r")) == NULL)
{
    perror("File open failed");
    exit(1);
}

if( MAX_PAGE >= (mem_size = atoi(argv[2])) )
{
    /* everything is fine we can go ahead */
    start_simulation();
}
else
{
         printf    ("\n\n\a\a\a******************************\n");
    printf("***************************************************\n");
    printf("**                                               **\n");
    printf("** Error:                                        **\n");
    printf("**                                               **\n");
    printf("** You are attempting to use a resident set size **\n");
    printf("** that is larger than the address space!        **\n");
    printf("**                                               **\n");
    printf("** The maximum address space size is: %-4d       **\n",MAX_PAGE);
    printf("**                                               **\n");
    printf("***************************************************\n");
    printf("***************************************************\n\n\n");

}
fclose(stream);

return 0;
  }

  void start_simulation(/*FILE * stream*/void)
     {

/*char *addr_buf;not used so removed --EC*/
int address;
int i, n;
list new_entry, current;

   /* initialise the page table */

for(i=0; i<MAX_PAGE;i++)
{
    pte[i].frame = -1;
    pte[i].valid = 0;
    pte[i].dirty = 0;
    pte[i].in_mem = 0;
    pte[i].next_ref=-1;

}

   /* initialise the resident set - empty*/

res_set_head = (list)malloc(sizeof(struct list_item));
res_set_head->next = res_set_head;
res_set_head->prev = res_set_head;

  /* initialise free list - all physical pages*/

free_list_head = (list)malloc(sizeof(struct list_item));
free_list_head->next = free_list_head;
free_list_head->prev = free_list_head;
current = free_list_head;

for(i=0; i<mem_size;i++)
{
    new_entry = (list)malloc(sizeof(struct list_item));
    current->next = new_entry;
    new_entry->prev = current;
    new_entry->next = free_list_head;
    new_entry->frame = i;
    current = new_entry;
    free_list_head->prev = current;
}

   /* main simulation loop */

while( (n = fscanf(stream, "%x", &address)) != -1)
{
   #ifdef DEBUG2
    printf("Reference %i -------------\n",total_ref);
   #endif

    resolve(address);
    total_ref++; 
}

free_mem(free_list_head);
free_mem(res_set_head);
display_stats();

return; 
   }

void resolve(int address)
  {
unsigned short frame_alloc;
int virt_page,i;
/*static int disp_counter = 0;not used so removed -EC*/

virt_page = address >> 8;
if (pte[virt_page].valid == 1)
{
    pte[virt_page].next_ref=distance_to_next_ref(virt_page);
   #ifdef DEBUG2
    printf("Page %i is valid, next reference is: %i\n",virt_page,pte  
          [virt_page].next_ref);
   #endif
}
else
{

    frame_alloc = find_frame();
    pte[virt_page].valid = 1;
    pte[virt_page].frame = frame_alloc;
    total_fault++;
    pte[virt_page].next_ref=distance_to_next_ref(virt_page);
    #ifdef DEBUG2
    printf("Page %i is being loaded, next reference is: %i\n",virt_page,pte
    [virt_page].next_ref);
   #endif
}
for(i=0;i<MAX_PAGE;i++)
    {
    if (pte[i].valid) pte[i].next_ref--;
    //if(pte[i].next_ref<=0) pte[i].next_ref=distance_to_next_ref(i);
    /* if the page is valid update the next ref time */
    }
    }

  unsigned short find_frame()
  {
unsigned short frame;
list current, new_tail;

if (free_list_head == free_list_head->prev)   /* free list empty */
{
    #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Free list empty finding frame\n");
    #endif

    frame = find_victim();
}
else
{
     #ifdef DEBUG
    printf("Free list not empty grabbing frame\n");
     #endif
    new_tail = free_list_head->prev->prev;
    new_tail->next = free_list_head;
    current = free_list_head->prev;
    free_list_head->prev = new_tail;

    to_resident_set(current);
    frame = current->frame;
}
return frame;
     }

 void to_resident_set(list current)
   {
list tail;

tail = res_set_head->prev;
tail->next = current;
current->next = res_set_head;
current->prev = tail;
res_set_head->prev = current;
     }


 unsigned short find_victim()
    {
int candidate,frame=-1,most_far=0,page;

for(candidate=0;candidate<MAX_PAGE;candidate++)
{

    if(pte[candidate].valid==1)
    {
    #ifdef DEBUG
   printf("\tValid Page %i is being examined, next reference is: %i\n",candidate,pte
         [candidate].next_ref);
   printf("Pt entry:\n\t\tFrame: %d\n\t\tValid: %d\n\t\tin_mem %d\n\t\tDirty: %
   d\n\t\tNext ref %d\n",pte[candidate].frame,pte[candidate].valid,pte
   [candidate].in_mem,pte[candidate].dirty,pte[candidate].next_ref);
   #endif
        if(  (pte[candidate].next_ref) < 0 ) 
        {
   #ifdef DEBUG
   printf("\t\t< 0 Page %i is being examined, next reference is: %i\n",candidate,pte
   [candidate].next_ref);
   #endif
            pte[candidate].valid=0;
            frame = pte[candidate].frame;
            pte[candidate].frame=-1;
            return frame;
        }
   #ifdef DEBUG
printf("Middle for page %i\n",candidate);
   #endif
if(most_far < (pte[candidate].next_ref) )
        {
    #ifdef DEBUG
   printf("\t\t> mf Page %i is being examined, next reference is: %i\n",candidate,pte
     [candidate].next_ref);
    #endif
   frame=pte[candidate].frame;
   most_far=pte[candidate].next_ref;
    }
   #ifdef DEBUG
   printf("Ending for page %i\n",candidate);
   #endif
    }   
}
invalidate(frame);
return frame;
 }


void invalidate(unsigned short frame)
  {
int i;

for(i=0;i<MAX_PAGE;i++)
{
    if (pte[i].frame == frame && pte[i].valid == 1)
    {
        pte[i].valid = 0;
        pte[i].frame = -1;
    #ifdef DEBUG
printf("Page %i is being evicted next ref is: %i\n",i,pte   [i].next_ref);
    #endif
        break;
    }

}
 }

 void display_stats()
    {
printf("\nProcess issued %d memory references\n", total_ref);
printf("Process triggered %d page faults\n", total_fault);
printf("Page fault rate is %d percent\n",((total_fault*100)/total_ref));
     }

 void free_mem(list head)
    {

list current,tail;

tail = head->prev;
current = head;

while (current->prev != tail)
{
    current = current->next;
    free(current->prev);
}
   }

 /* finds the distance to the next ref, returns -1 if never referenced again */

 int distance_to_next_ref(int frame)
   {
 long pos;
 int n,count;
 int address,page;  

if((pos=ftell(stream))==-1)
{
    printf("Error saving reference stream position\n");
    perror("Error was");
    fclose(stream);
    exit(1);
}

count=0;
while( (n = fscanf(stream, "%x", &address)) != -1)
{
            count++;    
    page=address>>8;
    if(page==frame)
    {
        if((fseek(stream,pos,SEEK_SET))==-1)
        {
printf("Error restoring the reference stream  position\n");
            perror("Error was:");
            fclose(stream);
        }

        return count;
    }
}
if((fseek(stream,pos,SEEK_SET))==-1)
{
    printf("Error restoring the reference stream position\n");
    perror("Error was:");
    fclose(stream);
}

return -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace your **two** printfs with

```
printf("Error restoring the reference stream position @ line %d\n", __LINE__);
```

I suspect the error does not come from where you thing it comes from.